# A man's breast vs. a woman's breasts

Tags: meaning, grammatical-gender

Why is it that breast is used when referring to a man's chest, but breasts is used for a woman's? Could breast also mean a woman's chest, or do breasts have to be used when referring to a woman's chest?

It seems strange that we speak as if there are two things when referring to a woman's chest but speak as if there is only one when referring to a man's.

Comment: Why did people vote to close this?

Comment: You should be able to see the reasons if you click on the _close_ link. At least, I think you can do that on your own questions.

Comment: It doesn't show the reasons.

Answer (score 8):

A women's chest is also called her breast but is typically only used with idioms:

> She beat her breast.
>
> I rest my head upon her breast.

Obviously, there is a bit of awkwardness regarding these sayings due to the specific meaning of individual breasts. But this actually isn't restricted to women either. A man also has two breasts that would correspond to each of his two nipples.

In short, the only difference between these words with regards to gender is that most people don't refer to male breasts — either as a whole or individually. This isn't a restriction of the words; people just don't make a big deal out of male breasts.

That being said, when they *are* being specifically referenced they are more commonly called *pects* or *pectorals* (which, again, is not a gender specific term) or the derogatory term *man boobs* which describes someone with sagging, overweight breasts.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the meaning of *breast* given from the NOAD contains:

- either of the two soft, protruding organs on the upper front of a woman's body that secrete milk after pregnancy.

  - the corresponding less-developed part of a man's body
  - a person's chest

Comment: There's a discrepancy here. The first description implies that a woman has two. The second implies that a man has only one.

Comment: @language hacker, you realise the definition @klamlaluno provided described a man's breast as "the *corresponding* *less-developed..."

Comment: The definition is for _breast_, and it says _either of_, which is singular, as in "they have a mortgage that will be repaid if **either of them dies**."